# Multiple instances of angular 2 directive on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a click-outside directive on a component which is created multiple times on the page. The component has a drop down I created which on click-outside of it closes the drop down. The problem is that when I have ~100 components with this drop down the click-outside directive gets called ~100 times for each component and this causes the simple action of opening a drop down to take too long.

This is the directive:

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Directive({ 
  selector: '[appClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  @Output() clickOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
    const isClickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!isClickedInside) {
      this.clickOutside.emit(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to stop the directive from running for all the drop downs?

thanks!